# WSO2 apictl configuration?

Tags: wso2

I am configuring WSO2 through script, is there a way to configure Advanced Policies, through scirpt.
As for the API I can download the yml using the download API utility and can push it using apictl, however couldn't figure a way to extract configured Advanced Policies and push it using script.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Regards
Diwakar

I am not getting any hint to do so.

Comment: What is your APIM version and what sort of advanced policies are you talking about? Advanced ratelimiting policies attached to the resource level or import ratelimiting policies created in one environment to another?

Comment: Hello @Lakshitha my APIM version is 4.1.0. I am configuring the APIM  on my local machine and have configured a ratelimiting policy, now when I, download the API from publisher, I get a YML file which I am storing in git repository.

Now when I import this yml file into another environment (wso2 running on some other server) then I am getting an error that the rate limiting policy which I defined is not present (which is obvious), now I want to import or somehow extract this advanced policy from my environment to be able to push in some other environment. 

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting and import rate-limiting policies is a [novel feature that we have introduced with APICTL 4.2.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/managing-rate-limiting-policies/migrating-rate-limiting-policies-to-different-environments/). Unfortunately for your 4.1.0 distribution, this is not supported and you have to manually create the rate-limiting policies in the other environment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, however when I am trying to download 4.2.0 version from the below link its still letting me download 4.1.0 . do you have the download link for 4.2.0 ?

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/  ---

Comment: This link is now updated with the latest release binaries. However please note that you need to use APIM 4.2.0 with the ctl 4.2.0.